# Need help to construct Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text as an example:

`\n\t\t\t\t\t3 comments`

Can anyone help me to construct PHP regex formula for extracting the number? (in this case `number = 3`)
The number can be prefixed by any text, but after the number there should be a `<space>` followed by `comments`.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it going to be a number up to 9, or any number?

Comment: any number starting from 0, so it might be 100 or so on

Comment: Okay, I posted a solution already, so that should do exactly that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\d+(?= comments)/', $text, $match);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = '\n\t\t\t\t\t3 comments';
if (preg_match('/(\d+)\scomments/', $text, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
} else {
    // the number was not found
}
```

This will match any number if it exists in the string and will assign it to the variable `$number`. If the number was not found, you can handle it in the `else` statement.

Comment: it gives me "3 comments". I only need "3" as the output. BTW, I found that the one posted by Karolis is working. Thanks anyway for your attention.

Comment: @tukang-coding if you use `$number = $match[1];` it will give you only the number, because this is stored in the capture group 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/(\d+)\s+comments/", $text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "\n\t\t\t\t\t3 comments";
preg_match('/\.*(\d+)\scomments/',$str,$m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```